# Are the injective functions dense in $C([0,1]^n,\mathbb R^n) $?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $n\geq 2$. Are injective functions dense in $C([0,1]^n,\mathbb R^n) $ with the uniform norm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and consider $f(z) = z^2$. If $g$ is close enough to $f$ then $\alpha \mapsto g(e^{i \alpha})$ stays in an annulus and winds around the origin twice, which cannot be done injectively.

Comment: Even simpler:  use $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x(x-1)$.  $f(1/2) = 1/4$, $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.  If $g$ is continuous and within $0.01$ of $f$, then $-0.01 \leq g(0) \leq 0.01$, $-0.01 \leq g(1) \leq 0.01$, and $0.24 \leq g(1/2) \leq 0.26$.  By intermediate value theorem, $g$ must attain the value $0.2$ twice, once in each subinterval.  This seems like it might have been an undergraduate real analysis homework problem :(.

Comment: To be fair, the OP specified $n\ge 2$

Comment: @A.DellaCorte Ah, overlooked this.  Martin probably has the simplest example then.